# Using negative height margin values to properly vertically align a control

Tags: xaml

I created a grid based XAML page. In the grid I display images which require no negative top margin, vertical, values. In my page I have two labels in textblocks that will not align properly in their grid stack panel with out using negative top margin values in the textblocks. The first label textblock I have to use a Margin="0,-35,0,0" and the second I have to use Margin="0, -650, 0, 0. The XAML is below please help.

```html
<Window
    x:Class="MasterPage.ApplicationInfoWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MasterPage"
    Title="Intake 4" Height="900" Width="1000" Background="#FFD9DDE8">
    <DockPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel >
                <Border Margin="0, 0, 0, 0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                <StackPanel Height="133" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="Images\header.jpg" Stretch="Fill" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="47"  />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Margin="3,0,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Image Source="Images\DSPASS_logo.png" Width="324" Stretch="Fill" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="80" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
                        <TextBlock FontSize="15" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Height="25" Margin="0,-35,0,0" >
                 <Label FontSize="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="Namelabel" Width="230" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#1664A1" Content="Name"/>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>

        </Border>

        <Border Margin="0, 0, 0, 0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">

                <StackPanel Background="wHITE" Height="358" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1">
                    <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="Images\silhouette.jpg" VerticalAlignment="Top"    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="320" Stretch="Fill" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="360" />
                </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                        <TextBlock FontSize="15"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="75" Margin="0, -650, 0, 0"  TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" >
                 <Label FontSize="35" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"   Name="Namelabel2" Width="640" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#1664A1" Content="Name"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        </StackPanel>


    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code:

1) When using a DockPanel you can't break the Visual Tree. Meaning the Controls you're docking have to be direct children of the DockPanel. For example:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" ... />
    <Label DockPanel.Dock="Right" .../>
</DockPanel>
```

Else the DockPanel will no longer be able to see/dock them. The same goes for a Grid and child Column/Row setting.

2) You're wrapping every Control in a Container. When this isn't necessary it only pollutes
the Visual Tree, in this case breaking the connections you're trying to make.

After refactoring the negative Margins are no longer needed:

```
<Window
    x:Class="MasterPage.ApplicationInfoWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MasterPage"
    Title="Intake 4" Height="900" Width="1000" Background="#FFD9DDE8">
    <StackPanel>
        <Border Margin="0, 0, 0, 0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <StackPanel Height="133" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Image Source="Images\header.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Height="47"  />
                <DockPanel Margin="3,0,0,5">
                    <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="Images\DSPASS_logo.png" Width="324" Stretch="Fill" Height="80" />
                    <Label DockPanel.Dock="Right" FontSize="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Name="Namelabel" Width="230" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#1664A1" Content="Name"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>    
        <Border Margin="0, 0, 0, 0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <DockPanel Background="White" Height="358" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="Images\silhouette.jpg" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="320" Stretch="Fill" Height="360" />
                <Label DockPanel.Dock="Right" FontSize="35" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Name="Namelabel2" Width="640" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#1664A1" Content="Name"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.  I need to add a grid below, I think. What I am adding are several rows and columns to display a label. Basically a table where some columns are different widths in each row. Is a grid what you recommend here?

Comment: @lelizabeth I like to use grids, they tend to give you more control then the other Containers. In return, it takes a little more code hooking them up. In your situation, when columns aren't always as wide, you could stack single Row Grids. Remember to use dummy Columns (with Width="*") to bridge the dead space.

Comment: As I said your post was great; however, their are two ways to skin a cat. I the other way was by just modifying a couple of properties and adding a new stack panel. As you can see new stackpanels were added using the attribute Orientation="Horizontal. So the grid now works without adding negative margin values. See below. I don't know if I need to add a new post about adding the sub-table as I mentioned above but if anyone has any ideas there that would help. Thanks.

Comment: @lelizabeth In XAML there are usually more than 2 ways to skin a cat :) Neverteless your sample has redundant code in many ways. Take the Grid at the top, it's not doing anything, since it has no children. It's not working as you claim. True, your horizontal StackPanel delivers same functionality as my DockPanel. Furthermore all the StackPanels that are wrapping Images and TextBlocks are polluting your code. The're not needed, since they aren't stacking. My sample is merely an example of how to strip the XAML down to the bones, so that it's maintainable and understandable.

Comment: Funk 31. Thanks again but bare with me as I'm just learning. Your posts are meaningful and help me learn.

Comment: Again Funk thank you very much. Now I understand.  I understand gridsplitters and just about everything else about using grids and nested grids. Yes I can pass a test of questions and answers but am still lost about the proper layout for the page I am creating. From your code I can now how to do the upper portion but an lost about how to finish my page.Now my confusion is the bottom part of my page needs to be as set of several vertically tables, two per row, with headers and three columns per table. I know you can't write my code for me but can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @lelizabeth Good to hear you're getting ahead. Sounds like you want to use a [DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) (see Remarks towards the end). There's plenty of info on this site and [others](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/datagrid-in-wpf/).

Comment: Thanks Funk! At this point it's time to study DataGrids. Again I learned at lot and thank.

Answer (score -1):

As I stated in my post I was using negative margin values in my XMAL to position controls. To prevent using Grids properly with StackPanels that contain nested Grids allows for proper vertical alignment.

Now to take care of horizontal alignment use of the following technique will handle this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation=Vertical />
    <StackPanel Orientation=Horizontal />
        content.....
    </StackPanel>
 </StackPanel>
```